# Solving a linear equation in an extension field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, matrix-equations

Let $\mathbb K$ a commutative field and $\mathbb L$ an extension field of $\mathbb K$ (that is to say a field that contains $\mathbb K$).

Let $A$ be a $n \times p$ matrix over $\mathbb K$.

Let $B$ be a $n \times 1$ matrix over $\mathbb K$.

Let $S_k=\{X,X \; \text{is a} \;p \times 1 \; \text{matrix over } \; \mathbb K \; \text{such that} \; AX=B \}$

Let $S_l=\{X,X \; \text{is a} \;p \times 1 \; \text{matrix over } \; \mathbb L \; \text{such that} \; AX=B \}$

Prove that $$S_k \neq \emptyset \Leftrightarrow S_l \neq \emptyset$$

Clearly the left-to-right implication is true. I have no clue how to do the converse though.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_l\ne\varnothing$. It is sufficiently to consider the case when
$n<p$ and ${\rm rank} A=n$. One can to choose values of $n$ unknowns arbitrary from $\mathbb{K}$ (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system)). Then others are expressed through them and coefficients of $A$, so they also belong to $\mathbb{K}$.